# Play Framework Deployment Failing

Tags: java, scala, deployment, playframework, sbt

We made a distribution of our Play Framework 2.5x app using activator dist.
Then unzipped the executable in the target/universal folder and ran the executable in the target/universal/app-ver-SNAPSHOT/bin/ folder using:

./executablename -Dplay.crypto.secret='key' on ubuntu
with the following error:

> **Error: Could not find or load main class**
>   **play.core.server.ProdServerStart**

Our build.sbt file is as follows:

```
name := """ods-web-tier"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  evolutions,
  "io.jsonwebtoken" % "jjwt" % "0.6.0",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36",
  "com.mashape.unirest" % "unirest-java" % "1.4.9"
)
sources in (Compile, doc) := Seq.empty
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false

playEbeanModels in Compile := Seq("models.*")
```

What are we missing here? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, I figured out the issue.

I just transferred the executable file only to the production server. Apparently, we need to transfer the entire zip or unzipped folder as it has the configurations and dependencies

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did not bundle the dependencies (JARs) you are using with your application. To do so, you can create a fat JAR using [`sbt assembly`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) or copy the entire folder produced by the `sbt dist` command on your server instead of just the executable.